form_validation_error python requests
im trying register to a website, but im taking this error:
{"account_created": false, "errors": {"force_sign_up_code": [{"message": "That code isn't valid. You can request a new one.", "code": "email_code_incorrect"}]}, "status": "ok", "error_type": "form_validation_error"}

My payload and headers:
    ###################### Signup Code ######################

    response_json = register_verification_code_post.json()
    signup_code = response_json['signup_code']
    print("Signup code:", signup_code)

    ###################### Final ######################

    finish_account_creation_post = {
        'email': email,
        'username': username,
        'first_name': first_name,
        'tos_version': 'row',
        'day': '24',
        'month': '8',
        'year': '1996',
        'force_sign_up_code': signup_code
    }

    finish_account_creation_headers = {
        'accept': '*/*',
        'user-agent': agent_User,
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'referer': 'https://www.goobin.com/accounts/',
        'x-csrftoken': csrf
    }

Did i put the 'force_sign_up_code' wrongly? i mean should it be like:
'force_sign_up_code': '{signup_code}'

???

You should ask the administrators of the website that you are trying to register on.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
